# NoSuchElementException even after isEmpty check

Tags: java, exception, linked-list, queue, nosuchelementexception

Im using a `LinkedList` in Java and have defined it as:

```
private final Queue<Collection<String>> data = new LinkedList<Collection<String>>();
```

The problem occurs when I try accessing it, like shown in this code:

```
synchronized (data) {
    if (data.isEmpty()) 
    {
        return;
    }
    data.remove();
}
```

This works well under most circumstances. But under some rare unknown scenario it throws the exception

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException
```

The exception is thrown at

```
data.remove();
```

As per my understanding the above exception is thrown if a remove is tried on the queue that is empty.
But I have already placed a check for `isEmpty()` before trying `remove()`.
Then why would it throw such an exception?
I've seen a number of similar posts about this but couldn't get a convincing answer. Since I have `synchronized` on the queue, I just do not understand the cause for this.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Can you provide a **complete**, repeatable example that illustrates this behavior?

Comment: "But under some rare unknown scenario it throws the exception..." This is part of the problem. In order to figure out the problem, you need to determine a scenario that throws the exception.

Comment: Are you modifying the list at other places in the code? Potentially witout using `synchronized`?

Comment: Yes, while adding to the list I do not synchronize it.

Comment: So don't - add with synchronization too

Comment: You should be synchronizing whenever you are changing the state of the collection.

Comment: Thanks guys. I have added the synchronization to the add method too. But I am not convinced about the exception. I only add valid data into the linked list. Then how can there be a NoSuchElementException, because this exception is thrown only when the list is empty. Even if my add is synchronized , how does it help in solving this specific issue.

Comment: Hello @Chinta. I have not specifically looked into your case, but I can say that all this may relate to how concurrency works. Every `Object` fires or supposed to fire the `notify` or `notifyAll` method when in such a context.
Perhaps, the problem is that when you do not synchronize your `add` operations, the `Thread` is not notified, therefore it does not hold the updated version of the `LinkedList`?